# Updating profiles and passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not sure on how to best tackle this issue - I need to validate a user's password when adding a new record and I also need to be able to validate when updating the passoword too. But how can I let a user update just part of their profile and perhaps leaving the password blank.

**Note** before you suggest allow_blank I am aware of this option but this is not suitable because when a user needs to change their password as a result of losing/forgetting it I don't want to allow user to have a blank password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an if statement to a validation:

`validates_presence_of :password, :if => :should_validate_password?

You should be able to pass a condition in here to catch whether the user is updating their password or not:

**Model**

```
def should_validate_password?
  updating_password || new_record?
end
```

**Controller**

```
@user.updating_password = true
@user.save
```

See here for more details: http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

**Updated:**

In your case I would create an if statement in the controller that detected whether any new password was being passed in the params. If so I would set `@user.updating_password = true` which would trigger the validation in the model. If not then `@user.updating_password` would be nil and the validation wouldn't trigger.

Comment: Looks useful - as this Railscast is quite old was this before the time of on create and on udpate? However, the concept of conditionals I should be able to make use of.

Comment: Yes, you can use the action based conditionals, but I thought you might need more granularity than just on a specific action.

Comment: But that's just it - I can't use the "action based conditionals" because there is no combination that will work for all scenarios

Comment: I need something that will allow blanks on update when using the edit page but not allow blanks when updating the password from the reset password page - so should be able to work with your suggestion to get that going

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. Use this more granular if statement approach to specify exactly what you need for your scenario.

Comment: Updated my answer to give you some more guidance on how I'd approach it.

Comment: It took me a long time to realise but this is the right answer - thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

```
validates :password, presence: true, if: lambda { |user| user.password_changed? }
```

by ActiveModel::Dirty (available on all models by default)

Answer (score 1):

### Fully custom way

Usually, `#password=` and `#password_confirmation=` are just virtual setters, the true attribute is  `#hashed_password` or something. So, you could do something like this :

```
class User
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  validate :validates_password
  validates_presence_of :hashed_password

  private

  def validates_password
    if password or password_confirmation
      if password != password_confirmation
        errors.add( :password, 'your message' )
      end
      # your others validations

      self.hashed_password = hash_password
    end
  end

  def hash_password
    # your hashing code
  end
end
```

When user is created providing password, virtual attributes `password` and `password_confirmation` are set, so `if` condition is true and validations are enforced.

When password is already set and user does not change it (an edit form without providing passwords), validation will not be enforced, because of `if password and password_confirmation`.

When password is already set and user change it, `password` and `password_confirmation` are set, so validation is triggered.

When you want to reset password, just set in your action `hashed_password` to nil. The model is now invalid because of `validates_presence_of :hashed_password` and user has to provide a new one.

### Using #has_secure_password

With `#has_secure_password`, rails will handle most of this, especially :

- it creates virtual atttributes
- it will trigger validation for confirmation match only if password attributes are provided
- it will hash password

So, what you need is just adding your own validations, doing it only when `password` or `password_confirmation` are present.

```
class User
  has_secure_password
  validate :validates_password

  private

  def validates_password
    if password or password_confirmation
      unless <your_test>
        errors.add( :password, '<your error message>' )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As previously, this will only be triggered if password and password_confirmation are provided, which only happens if user submitted them as form data (as real attribute is `password_digest`).

Comment: thanks - but how does this let users enter blanks on edit page and require non-blanks for the reset password? both of which are update actions.

Comment: `if password or password_confirmation` will avoid validating field if none is provided. `validates_presence_of :ashed_password` will trigger error if not providing password when it never has been provided. For the reset_password, just set `#hashed_password` to nil in your action before trying to save the record.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see in your code how edit password and reset password are treated differently??? The `if password or password_confirmation` would be ignored on both occassions - and would I need attr_accessor in Rails4?

Comment: sorry just seen your revision - one moment

Comment: Ok - I'm getting it - interesting approach - but one more thing. Why do I need the hash_password action?

Comment: That's a standard security measure. You don't store passwords in plain text in databases, so that any cracker dumping your database won't be able to retrieve user passwords. This usually involve [salting and hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: sorry I didn't mean why hash passwords - I meant why the action? I am using has_secure_password which is pretty standard these days - can't that take care of things?

Comment: Yep, if you want to use standard hashing, `#has_secure_password` is the way to go. I just assumed you wanted fine grain algorithm tweaks since you don't use an authentication library.

Comment: so finally - in the last part of your answer - when you say set hashed_password to nil - you mean to do this in the controller right?

Comment: Using `#has_secure_password`, the code is way simpler. I edit my answer.

Comment: excellent - will have a play with this later and mark it correct. cheers for the help

Comment: You're welcome. Just a side note about naming : "I meant why the action?". This is not an action - an action is the name we give to controller methods that are related to a route. The correct name is just "method".

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this -  private chat?